# add new viewController in xCode 6

Tags: viewcontroller, xcode6

I need to add a new viewController (new file h. and m.) using xCode 6 beta. After I go to File > New > File I do not get the option to add an "Object-C class" as I used to do in xCode 5. Doing that I normally got a new h. and m. file appearing in the Navigation area.

Any one can help pls?

PS - I am a beginner trying to learn basics of "storyboard" :)

thanks

Answer (score 6):

If you choose objective-c File in your screenshot , you will get a .m file and a .h file written in Objective-C
If you choose Cocoa Touch File , you will have a option of Objective-C and Swift File which can be subclasses of other cocoa touch classes such as UIViewController or UITableViewCell.
IF you choose Swift File , you will get a single empty Swift file.
Since you are a beginner writing code with Objective-C , you'd better choose Objective-c File directly

Answer (score 3):

Right click on the group (folder) in the navigation area in which you want to add the new viewController. Select New File, and then select Cocoa Touch Class.

Comment: thanks a lot for helping :) tried and I swear that there is not that option available. I went thru all of the options available: the closest is "object-C file" but it seems to be a different thing ... screenshot here https://www.dropbox.com/s/si7u7jusv0zkshp/Screen%20Shot%202014-07-23%20at%2021.01.03.png

Comment: Sorry, I was thinking xCode 5. Edited my answer for xCode 6 beta.

Comment: OMG! fantastic ... you made my day :) so hard to solve this little stuff as beginner :) thanks